How to set the worker for Pdfjs-dist in a Tauri app?
I want to parse a pdf in a Tauri+Sveltekit desktop application. For that I have to set a worker for pdfjs. While in a web environment the below code might work flawlessly (and it also works in development mode), URL() cannot be used in a release-built Tauri app:
let pdfjsLib = await import('pdfjs-dist');
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs', import.meta.url).pathname;
let myPdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(buffer).promise; // PDFDocumentProxy

Importing it also does not work as in a regular web app:
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs?url';
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker

I also do not want to import the worker from a web-url as the program should work without internet connection.
So what is the right solution to set the worker?

The complication is that Tauri packs the whole sveltekit app into a single exe in which I cannot refer to URLs as in a web application and so it does not simply let me access the node_modules folder which is one level above the source folder. Of course I can just copy the required file into my source folder to access it but it is not elegant and I also need to keep it synched every time I update the pdfjs module.
